# Is there a standardised noise source symbol for circuit diagrams?

Tags: noise, symbol, diagram

Does anyone know of any standard symbol for a noise source, for example of one wants to represent the Johnson-Nyquist noise, what is best to use?

Comment: You can see some symbols used on this Wiki page: [Johnson-Nyquist Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise). But I just made up one for fun, too: \$\require{enclose}\enclose{box}{\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\overset{\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})}{\hookrightarrow}}}\$

Comment: @jonk I quite like yours! Put it in a circle and we've got a deal. Thanks for the reference, do you happen to know if this is a standard?

Comment: No. I've no clue if there even is a standard. If there was a standard for it in the general EE area I'd probably have seen it. There may be standards within narrow little Ph.D. niches where they have to communicate and have developed their own "language" out of sheer need. But I've not been exposed to them, if so.

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsdMoBgSch1523zysEujpwjohQDEqiCNicVw&usqp=CAU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many noise sources are best thought of as current noise, or voltage noise, and for those, just use a 'two circle' or 'single circle' current generator or voltage generator respectively, with an appropriate resistor if they have a finite impedance. When I've used a noise diode, I've used a diode symbol.

Putting a circle round a component is often quite a good hint that it's a 'bit more' than just a diode, or a voltage source.